# View Binding in Custom Views

Tags: android, kotlin, view

Previously I was using Kotlin Synthetics in my project. Now shifted to view Binding. I am having problems in viewBinding to bind the view in custom views.

I have 2 layouts named as `fragment_single.xml` and `fragment_double.xml`.

I am inflating both the layouts in `fragment` as below

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val view: View =
            if (centered) {
                _fragmentFxlLayoutSingleBinding = FragmentFxllayoutSingleBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
                fragmentFxlLayoutSingleBinding.root
            } else {
                _fragmentFxlLayoutDoubleBinding = FragmentFxllayoutDoubleBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
                fragmentFxlLayoutDoubleBinding.root
            } 
}
```

Now I have custom view as `Fxllayout` which extends `Framelayout` and want to inflate the same binding in custom view. But I am getting error in custom view when I inflate the layout.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bolindadigital.BorrowBoxLibrary.debug, PID: 29575
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.bolindadigital.BorrowBoxLibrary.debug:layout/fragment_fxllayout_double: Binary XML file line #10 in com.bolindadigital.BorrowBoxLibrary.debug:layout/fragment_fxllayout_double: Error inflating class com.bolinda.digital.library.mobile.android.readium2.libs.navigator.fxl.R2FXLLayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.bolindadigital.BorrowBoxLibrary.debug:layout/fragment_fxllayout_double: Error inflating class com.bolinda.digital.library.mobile.android.readium2.libs.navigator.fxl.R2FXLLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.bolinda.digital.library.mobile.android.readium2.libs.navigator.fxl.R2FXLLayout.<init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:822)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at com.bolindadigital.BorrowBoxLibrary.databinding.FragmentFxllayoutDoubleBinding.inflate(FragmentFxllayoutDoubleBinding.java:80)
        at com.bolinda.digital.library.mobile.android.readium2.libs.navigator.fxl.R2FXLLayout.init(R2FXLLayout.kt:189)
        at com.bolinda.digital.library.mobile.android.readium2.libs.navigator.fxl.R2FXLLayout.<init>(R2FXLLayout.kt:1187)
        at com.bolinda.digital.library.mobile.android.readium2.libs.navigator.pager.R2FXLPageFragment.onCreateView(R2FXLPageFragment.kt:231)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2995)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:523)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1758)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1670)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:323)
        at com.bolinda.digital.library.mobile.android.readium2.libs.navigator.pager.R2FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(R2FragmentPagerAdapter.kt:133)
        at com.bolinda.digital.library.mobile.android.readium2.libs.navigator.pager.R2RTLViewPager$ReversingAdapter.finishUpdate(R2RTLViewPager.java:338)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:540)
        at com.bolinda.digital.library.mobile.android.readium2.libs.navigator.pager.R2RTLViewPager.setAdapter(R2RTLViewPager.java:101)
        at com.bolinda.digital.library.mobile.android.readium2.libs.navigator.epub.R2EpubActivity$calculateResourcePagerAdapterState$1.invokeSuspend(R2EpubActivity.kt:754)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at androidx.lifecycle.DispatchQueue.drainQueue(DispatchQueue.kt:75)
        at androidx.lifecycle.DispatchQueue.enqueue(DispatchQueue.kt:112)
        at androidx.lifecycle.DispatchQueue.access$enqueue(DispatchQueue.kt:31)
        at androidx.lifecycle.DispatchQueue$dispatchAndEnqueue$$inlined$with$lambda$1.run(DispatchQueue.kt:100)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
```

I am inflating layout in custom view as below.

```
private fun init(context: Context) {
    _fragmentFxlLayoutDoubleBinding = FragmentFxllayoutDoubleBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, false)
    _fragmentFxlLayoutSingleBinding = FragmentFxllayoutSingleBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, false)
   
}
```

What is wrong in this code? Why error in custom view?

Comment: That Exception is saying that the `R2FXLLayout` class is missing a public constructor that takes both a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`, in that order. It's required for inflation from layout XML.

Comment: If I include that constructor then while opening the document it gets freeze and app cause error which is not displaying in logcat but after that I have to kill the app and open the document again. I can deffinitely tell that it is due to viewBinding because previously I was using `Kotlin Synthetics` and working fine.

Comment: I'm just telling you what that stack trace is saying. It is unambiguous. I can't offer any real suggestions without a [mcve]. I'm not even sure if the `R2FXLLayout` is the `Fxllayout` you mention in the description, since you've not shown either of those classes.

Comment: Actually, I suppose I can offer one suggestion, upon rereading this. You don't want to inflate a `Fragment`'s layout inside your custom `View`, especially if that layout contains the custom `View` itself, 'cause that's just infinite recursion. If you're just trying to make the `Fragment`'s layout into a single custom `View`, then the layout/binding you inflate inside the `View` should contain only the children of the original `<FrameLayout>`, but inside `<merge>` tags, not `<…R2FXLLayout>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I believe instead of inflating two different files if you could create one more file and use the **include** tag in it to include your *fragment_single.xml*  and *fragment_double.xml* then use the visibility attribute based on your logic to show/hide either of them.

Comment: Actually, this is the custom view. But this same layouts are also inflating in fragment. In fragment I have inflated as `if(centered) fragment_single else fragment_double`.